# Getting a summary of compiler warnings

Tags: makefile, g++, warnings, compiler-warnings

Is there a way I can get a summary of all the compiler-warnings at the end of the build ? Using g++ on a Makefile

Comment: Only by writing your own script to grep them out of the make output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own make command for compilation and use it in your recipes. You could, for instance, automatically log the standard and error outputs of your compiler to text files and `grep` them all for warnings at the end of your build. Something like (with GNU make):

```
# $(1): source file
# $(2): object file
# $(3): log file
MYCXX = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(1) -o $(2) 2>&1 | tee $(3)

CXXFLAGS += -Wall -pedantic

%.o: %.cpp
    $(call MYCXX,$<,$@,$*.log)

OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))
LOGS := $(patsubst %.o,%.log,$(OBJS))

top: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
    @printf '\nSummary of warnings\n###################\n\n'
    @for l in $(LOGS); do grep -i -10 warning $$l || true; done
```

Demo:

```
$ make
g++ -Wall -pedantic -c b.cpp -o b.o 2>&1 | tee b.log
g++ -Wall -pedantic -c c.cpp -o c.o 2>&1 | tee c.log
g++ -Wall -pedantic -c a.cpp -o a.o 2>&1 | tee a.log
g++ -Wall -pedantic -c d.cpp -o d.o 2>&1 | tee d.log
c.cpp: In function ‘int c()’:
c.cpp:1:18: warning: unused variable ‘vc’ [-Wunused-variable]
 int c(void) {int vc; return 0;}
                  ^~
a.cpp: In function ‘int a()’:
a.cpp:1:18: warning: unused variable ‘va’ [-Wunused-variable]
 int a(void) {int va; return 0;}
                  ^~
b.cpp: In function ‘int b()’:
b.cpp:1:18: warning: unused variable ‘vb’ [-Wunused-variable]
 int b(void) {int vb; return 0;}
                  ^~
g++  b.o c.o a.o d.o -o top

Summary of warnings
###################

b.cpp: In function ‘int b()’:
b.cpp:1:18: warning: unused variable ‘vb’ [-Wunused-variable]
 int b(void) {int vb; return 0;}
                  ^~
c.cpp: In function ‘int c()’:
c.cpp:1:18: warning: unused variable ‘vc’ [-Wunused-variable]
 int c(void) {int vc; return 0;}
                  ^~
a.cpp: In function ‘int a()’:
a.cpp:1:18: warning: unused variable ‘va’ [-Wunused-variable]
 int a(void) {int va; return 0;}
                  ^~
```

There is even a slightly more elegant way that consists in (re-)defining the `CXX` standard make variable and assign it a small shell script that does the job, such that you can use `CXX` as you would normally:

```
CXX = function mycxx { g++ $$* 2>&1 | tee $(patsubst %.o,%.log,$@) ;}; mycxx

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

When expanded by make for the `foo.o` target the recipe becomes:

```
function mycxx { g++ $* 2>&1 | tee foo.log ;}; mycxx -Wall -pedantic foo.cpp -o foo.o
```

And the shell will finally execute:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic foo.cpp -o foo.o 2>&1 | tee foo.log
```

The final result should be the same as with the first solution but with significantly less modifications of your Makefile. Apart the (re-)definition of `CXX`, it should remain the same (assuming you were using `CXX` in your recipes, which is recommended).